# Free word building in Interlingua

Tags: vocabulary, interlingua, morphology

There is even a Wikipedia article on [Free word building in Interlingua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_word-building_in_Interlingua) stating that it is feasible to apply derivational affixes in Interlingua productively even when none of the so-called *control languages* uses a specific derivation.

However, the Wikipedia article has a lack of real-world examples of such Interlingua words. How productive is *Free word building* in Interlingua? What are some sample words that are actually used in Interlingua?

Comment: I don't see where the wikipedia article says that one can apply derivational affixes in Interlingua *even when none of the control languages uses a specific derivation.* I cannot find any text saying such in the article.

Comment: @Sparksbet I expect the reference is to this line: "For example, jada (jade) can be used to form jadificar, (to jadify, make into jade, make look like jade), jadification, and so on. These word forms would be impermissible in English but would be good Interlingua." None of the control languages has a form "jadification", but it is apparently permissible Interlingua.